# Is there any suggestion to add jQuery dynamically with a self executing function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to import jQuery in a JS file dynamically. Here is my code:

```js
(function() {
  var head = document.querySelector("head")[0];
  if (head.classList.contains("En-Script") == true) {
    head.classList.add("En-Script");
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    let EnScript = document.querySelector(".En-Script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "./jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
    EnScript.appendChild("script");
  } else {
    console.log("class_list_added_for_further_process");
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("jquery added successfully")
  });
})();
```

Comment: Only use tags that are related to your question, and read the description of those. `css` is not relevant for your question, and `script` says `DON'T USE THIS TAG! Every SO question is about scripts one way or another`. And especially as a beginner, you should make use of code formatting.

Comment: What problem do you have with your code? Do you get any error messages in the developer console of your browser.

Comment: What is the purpose of this condition `if (head.classList.contains("En-Script") == true) {` why do you have that in you code?

Comment: Actually there is problem called "unexpected token " I tried to add a condition to add class and then by adding the class , I can append child script tag in it

Comment: The edited question help me a lot thanks 

Comment: `to add class and then by adding the class, I can append child script tag in it` why do you need a class to append a child? I mean you already need the element to add the class in the first place, so you then could already append the child to it. There are various problems in your code making it hard to understand why you did certain things.

Comment: Actually sir I tried this `var head = document.getElementsByTagName ("head"); ` and head.appendChild("script") , I also have a variable for script ,,, and it's giving an error "head.appendChild" Is not a function so I tried to do it by a class,,

Comment: Here is a guideline for you on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems in your code.

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns one element, and not an array, so `document.querySelector("head")[0]`makes no sense.
- With `if (head.classList.contains("En-Script") == true) {` you test if `head` has the class `En-Script`, which makes no sense in combination with `head.classList.add("En-Script")`
- Also adding a class to the head to check if the script is loaded is probably not the best approach, if you want to do that add a class or data attribute to the `script` element you append.
- If you already have `head` why do you use `let EnScript = document.querySelector(".En-Script");` to query for it again?
- `EnScript.appendChild("script");` tries to append test string with the content `script` to `EnScript` and not the element you created and stored in the `script` variable.
- `$(document).ready(function() {` would not wait for the script to be loaded.
- Calling `.ready(` for when you loaded jQuery dynamically also does not make much sense because the DOM is already read.

That's how loading a script could look like:

```js
(function() {
  var head = document.querySelector("head");

  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";

  script.onload = function() {
    // called when the script is loaded and ready to use
    console.log("jquery added successfully")
  }
  script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js";

  head.appendChild(script);

})();
```

Comment: Yes you got the exact problem, I think I have to watch some tutorials about that and also read some books before practicals , thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong, you were checking if head had the class `"En-Script"` and then adding the class to the head, so I changed the validation so it makes sense.
Then, you were selecting the head using `querySelector` which only returns 1 value and using `[0]` which would work if you were using `querySelectorAll` instead.

Then you should add the jquery function `$(document)` after the script has loaded, so I added a `script.onload` to achieve this.

Also when you append a child you should send the object you created, not a string, so instead of this `EnScript.appendChild("script");`  I used `head.appendChild(script);`

```js
(function() {

  var head = document.querySelector("head");
  if (!head.classList.contains("En-Script")) {
    head.classList.add("En-Script");
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";
    script.onload = function() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("jquery added successfully")
      });

    };
    head.appendChild(script);
  } else {
    console.log("class_list_added_for_further_process");
  }


})();
```